# Does Windows service needs to be rebuild after changing config file?

Tags: vb.net, windows-services

I changed config file of the windows many times. Before changing config file I stopped the service and after changing config file, started again. Every thing worked fine.

But last time when I made some changes in config file of the windows service and started it - It didnt worked, I even tried reinstalling the service but in vain.

As a last resort I rebuild the service with new config file and copied newly build files on the server and installed the service. To my surprise the Windows service worked perfectly this time.But I have only made changes to config file and the code of the windows service was untouched. My question is, do we need to rebuild the Window service if we change the config file many time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're referring to the automatically generated .config file, then no, the service need not be rebuilt. My guess is that in your last iteration you forgot an end tag or something, which caused the service to fail to load it's configuration.

Comment: This is not the case.. I copy pasted same config file and build my system without making any changes.. Has there been any missing end tags my service would not have got build.